# Comparing Excel Cells to form a While Loop in C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create a loop that uses two excel cells to control how long that loop will last.  The number of loops will change throughout the program, so it can not be a constant.  I have been trying to use

```
 while  (activesheet.Range["C" + n].Value == activesheet.Range["C" + (n + 1)].Value)
            {
                //Do stuff...
            }
```

However, the program skips over this step because it is not actually comparing cells.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my own error, syntax. I actually did not have the .Value in my code for the second comparison. ..my mistake
I had:

`while  (activesheet.Range["C" + n].Value == activesheet.Range["C" + (n + 1)])`

my question had to correct code the entire time.